# recursive relation for generating sequence whose ratio converges to phi+k, where phi is golden ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Does there exist any general recursive relation which can generate sequence whose ratio of t(n+1)/tn converges to phi+k, where tn indicates nth term of the sequence , k is a natural number and phi is golden ratio?

Comment: Find the monic quadratic polynomial that has $\phi+k$ as a root, that will give you the recurrence you seek.

Comment: if you dont mind ,can you give me one example for phi+2 please?@GerryMyerson

Comment: So, wait, can you not find a quadratic that has $\phi+2=(5+\sqrt5)/2$ as a root? Let $x=(5+\sqrt5)/2$. Multiply by two. Subtract five. Square both sides. Expand, and combine like terms. Can you do that?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: no,i got it.Thank you@GerryMyerson

Comment: Good. Let me encoourage you to write it up, and post it as an answer.

Comment: You could do that today.

Comment: @GerryMyerson i got x^2-10x-5(5)^(1/2)=0

Comment: But there should be a monic polynomial with integer coefficients. $x=(5+\sqrt5)/2$; $2x=5+\sqrt5$; $2x-5=\sqrt5$; $(2x-5)^2=5$; $4x^2-20x+25=5$; $4x^2-20x+20=0$; $x^2-5x+5=0$. Now the question is, do you know how to get from $x^2-5x+5=0$ to the recurrence that you have asked for?

Comment: @GerryMyerson To be honest i don't know how to get the recurrence from there?

Comment: OK, from $x^2-5x+5=0$ you write down $a_{n+2}-5a_{n+1}+5a_n=0$. The general solution to that recurrence is $a_n=Ar^n+Bs^n$, where $r$ and $s$ are the two solutions to $x^2-5x+5=0$, and where $A$ and $B$ are constants that depend on $a_0$ and $a_1$. Now, see if you can do the general case, $\phi+k$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you so much for teaching me something new.